# How to take the first or last row in Oracle SQL if you are checking a Count() value

Tags: oracle, count, row, row-number

I'm trying to obtain the first (or last) row of one sql query where, the column i need to inspect, is, in fact a count() result.

I notice than in the inet i can find some workarrounds to find them but just when they are indexers and the info doesn't repeat, and the thing is, in this one it repeats itselfs, i receive three values than are exactly equal and is dropping them all together here, in other words, i'm receiving 4 rows instead of 2.

Did anyone know how to cut off the 2 rows and just select one?

Here is the code:

```
Create view TotalEmpleadosPorDepto as 
Select DEPARTMENT_NAME DEPARTAMENTO, count(EMPLOYEE_ID) TOTAL_EMPLEADOS
from DEPARTMENTS join EMPLOYEES USING(DEPARTMENT_ID) 
group by DEPARTMENT_NAME
order by DEPARTMENT_NAME;

select TotalEmpleadosPorDepto.DEPARTAMENTO "DEPARTAMENTO",
TotalEmpleadosPorDepto.TOTAL_EMPLEADOS "TOTAL EMPLEADOS" 
from TotalEmpleadosPorDepto
where TotalEmpleadosPorDepto.TOTAL_EMPLEADOS =
(select Max (TOTAL_EMPLEADOS) from TotalEmpleadosPorDepto)
or
TotalEmpleadosPorDepto.TOTAL_EMPLEADOS =
(select FIRST_VALUE(min (TOTAL_EMPLEADOS)) from TotalEmpleadosPorDepto)
order by DEPARTAMENTO;
```

Thanks in advance

PS: Any question, suggestion or comment to improve the question would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by first or last row? The row with the largest or smallest value of count(EMPLOYEE_ID)? What should be selected if there are two or more departments tied for the most (or the least) number of employees?

Comment: It would also help if you would add a small example: here are the departments, and their counts, here is the current output, here is why it doesn't match my needs, and here is what I actually need. It can be a small, made-up example just to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE or inline view to assign ranking using the [analytic `rank()` or `dense_rank()` functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm):

```
select departamento, total_empleados
from (
  select departamento, total_empleados,
    rank() over (order by total_empleados) as rnk1,
    rank() over (order by total_empleados desc) as rnk2
  from totalempleadospordepto
)
where rnk1 = 1 or rnk2 = 1;
```

which should give you the same result as your existing query, including showing multiple rows where there are ties.

To only get one row for the highest and lowest values *could* use `row_number()` instead, as that doesn't duplicate ranking numbers:

```
select departamento, total_empleados, rnk1, rnk2
from (
  select departamento, total_empleados,
    row_number() over (order by total_empleados) as rnk1,
    row_number() over (order by total_empleados desc) as rnk2
  from totalempleadospordepto
)
where rnk1 = 1 or rnk2 = 1;
```

... but which of the duplicate rows you get is indeterminate. It's better to specify how ties should be broken, with additional `order by` expressions - for example using the `departamento`:

```
select departamento, total_empleados
from (
  select departamento, total_empleados,
    rank() over (order by total_empleados, departamento) as rnk1,
    rank() over (order by total_empleados desc, departamento desc) as rnk2
  from totalempleadospordepto
)
where rnk1 = 1 or rnk2 = 1;
```

With what you've shown that still seems rather arbitrary, but would at least give consistent results.